# auth0 and azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, auth0

I would like to take user details from Microsoft AZURE Active Directory and let that user login through auth0.

Additionally I want all the user in azure active directory to get provisioned into auth0 database.

Answer (score 1):

To enable the app to authenticate with auth0 which also support Microsoft Azure AD accounts, we need to config auth0 to connect the Azure AD. You can refer [this document](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory/v2) for the detailed steps.

And after you login using the Azure AD account, it should be provisioned into auth0 database automatically. You can check the uses using the [API Explorer](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users) provided by auth0 to check the users.